# Jquery returning all to much data I only want the table

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hi im attempting to use jquerys ajax to update a form after a GET request, I simply want  the table to update but it send through the page headers as well.

First Here is my script, its small so i will include it all,

```
var wishorder = {
    init: function(config){
        this.config = config;
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function(){
        this.config.itemSelection.on('click',this.addWish);
    },
    addWish: function(e){
        console.log('working');

        var self = wishorder;
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                sku: $(this).data('sku'),
                action: $(this).data('action'),
                qty: $(this).data('qty')
            },
            success: function(results){
                //here is where is would like to repopulate the div
                //but its outputting the whole page
                console.log(results);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }


};
wishorder.init({
    itemSelection: $('#carttable a'),
    form: $('#cartfrm')
});
```

I can see that it is returning the results i want but it wraps it in html as in page header.

Here are the php function its calling.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_GET['action'] == 'move'){

  list($sp_type, $pid) = $this->parse_sku($_GET['sku']);
  $qty =  (filter_var($_GET['qty'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' >= 1)))?$_GET['qty']:1;
  $q = "CALL add_to_wish_list('$this->uid', '$sp_type', $pid, $qty)";
  $this->query($q);
  $q = "CALL remove_from_cart('$this->uid', '$sp_type', $pid)";
  $this->query($q);
  $q = "CALL get_shopping_cart_contents('$this->uid')";
  $this->query($q);
  $this->read();
  $this->outcart();
  exit();
}
```

and the outcart function wich generates the html for the div

```
function outcart(){
  echo "<div id=\"cartcont\" class=\"cartitems\"><form action=\"/cart.php\" method=\"post\"><table id=\"carttable\"><tr class=\"theads\"> <th class=\"titm\" >Item</th> <th >Quantity</th> <th >Price</th> <th>Subtotal</th> <th class=\"topt\" >Options</th>";
  $total = 0;
  while($row = $this->_result->fetch_object()){
    $price = $this->get_just_price($row->price, $row->sale_price);
    $subtotal = $price * $row->quantity;
    $total += $subtotal;
    echo "<tr class=\"tdata\">
            <td>".$row->category." :: ".$row->name."</td>
            <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"quantity[".$row->sku."]\" value=\"$row->quantity\" size=\"2\">
            <td>$".$price."</td>
            <td>$".number_format($subtotal, 2)."</td> 
            <td><a href=\"/wishlist.php?sku=".$row->sku."&amp;action=move&amp;qty=".$row->quantity."\" class=\"buttoncart black\">&nbsp;&nbsp; Move To Wishlist &nbsp;&nbsp;</a><br><a href=\"/cart.php?sku=".$row->sku."&amp;action=remove\" class=\"buttoncart black\">&nbsp;Remove From Cart &nbsp;</a></td>";
  }

  echo "</tr><tr class=\"ttotals\"><td colspan=\"3\" ><strong id=\"carttotal\">TOTAL:</strong></td>
                <td colspan=\"2\" >&nbsp;&nbsp; $".number_format($total,2) ." </td>
                </tr>";
  echo "</table>";

  echo "<div id=\"cartmnbtns\"><p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"UPDATE QUANTITIES\" class=\"buttoncart1 green\"><br><a href=\"https://".BASE_URL."/checkout.php?session=".$this->uid."\" class=\"buttoncart1 green \">Checkout</a></p> </div></form>";
}
```

So i just want to repopulate the table really or the cartcont div with the results, where am missing the point?

Comment: I don't see anything that would add a page header, it has to be coming from the PHP. Are you sure that function is the only thing that's called?

Comment: yes i look to make sure

Answer (score 1):

The page you're calling is `url: $(this).attr('href')` and that's a web-page you're just on with all headers and stuff... You have to put your functions in a separate .php file that doesn't contain a whole web-page frame and only outputs the text you want.

If that's not possible then create in your success callback function with `document.createDocumentFragment()`, pass the whole response inside the fragment and pull out your stuff you need with something like `myHTML = docFrag.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]` and then pass this with append to your form.

You might also want to set something like `contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8"` in your ajax call.

By the way: If you're not using the convenience of parsing variables inside strings you might want to use a different way (the other quotes) of writing your strings, as it's then faster, so:

```
echo '<tr class="tdata">...'
```

Comment: affraid im still really lost